# Alamofire - Add a timeout if there is no response

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a JSON call using Alamofire, it works well except if the query on the server is not responding. If the endpoint times out then Alamofire does give a timeout error but recently the endpoint was working but MSSQL on the server was not responding. In that case, the SVProgress would just spin and wait for the server to return the response and would not timeout.

How can I add a timeout to the below code so that if the server is not responding after x seconds I get an error?

I'm using Swift 5.

```
SVProgressHUD.show()
let apiEndpoint: String = "https://intelipos.dynalias.net/iocserver/MobileApp.aspx?action=MobileApp"
let headers = HTTPHeaders(["Content-Type" : "application/json","WebSiteAppID":self.webSiteAppID])
var param = [String: Any?]()
param["Command"] = "GetSales"
let keychain = KeychainSwift()
let sessionID = keychain.get("adminSessionID")!.base64Decoded()!
let strParam = jsonToString(json: ["SessionID":sessionID])
param["Data"] = strParam?.base64Encoded()
param["Signature"] = strParam?.base64Encoded()?.sha256Signature()

let request =  AF.request(URL(string: apiEndpoint)!, method: .post, parameters: param as Parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the timeout interval of your url request to your desired value.

```
request.timeoutInterval = 30
```